# Firefox doesn't change favicon.svg prefers-color-scheme from light to dark

Tags: javascript, html, svg, firefox

I am trying to change favicon.svg color via CSS media-tag inside of that SVG. At Chrome and Microsoft Edge it works fluently except Firefox.
The logic is that I switch my Windows 10 default app theme to dark mode, so that my favicon changes from black to white color on my browser.
So when I do that, my Firefox-browser theme changing as well, but icon doesn't change its color like other browsers do.
What could be the reason for such strange Firefox behaviour?
Even with **ui.systemUsesDarkTheme 1**
[image: systemUsesDarkTheme]

Comment: @RobertLongson, sure I did

Comment: As of writing the latest firefox is v101. This seems to be a bug and has been fixed and targeted for release with v103 (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1772632)